# Отправка HTML писма через Phpmailer

Tags: php

У меня в отдельном файле html есть готовое письмо. Мне нужно его отправить на почту через phpmailer, но я незнаю как его закинуть в php.

Comment: через attachment Phpmailer или в тело письма через `file_get_contents`

Comment: можно по подробней на счет attachment

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#file-attachments

Comment: Зачем прикреплять файл с письмом если нужно показать его содиржимое в писме?

Comment: Наверное, затем, что вы сами ничего конкретного не говорите - ни что за файл, ни как он используется - НИ-ЧЕ-ГО. Рекомендую вам прочитать в Помощи о том, как лучше задавать вопросы, и на какие вопросы у вас будет выше шанс получить ответ. Пока что он слишком размыт чтобы дать на него точный ответ, а разводить обсуждения и выяснения в комментариях - это на любителя.

Comment: Добавлю к комментарию выше. Вы сами просили подробнее про attachment. Вторым вариантом я указал "в теле письма". В той же документации есть пример.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sender = new PHPMailer();
  $sender->isHTML();
  ...
  $sender->Body = file_get_content('my.html');
  ...
  $sender->send();
```